# Ajustar alto de un div segun el tamaño de los otros div

Tags: html5, css3, web, diseño, grid

tengo un contenedor grid con las sgtes propiedades `style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%; column-gap:.5rem; grid-row-gap:.5rem;">`
lo cual me da por resultado lo sgte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como hacer para que los elementos que se van mostrando abajo se acomoden al alto del elemento de arriba y no al alto del elemento mas alto como se acomoda actualmente, es decir, para hacerlo mas facil de entender, como coloco los elementos de abajo inmediatamente abajo del alto del elemento de arriba como las flechas

Answer (score 0):

Ps me respondo yo mismo por si a alguien le llega a servir, no pude encontrar una solución con css puro, por lo que no se si se podrá imagino que si.

utilicé el complemento Masonry, aquí el link https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js
es muy facil de utilizar simplemente haces esto

```
<script>
    $('#grid').masonry({
        columnWidth: '.box',
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });
</script>
```

espero a alguien algun dia le sirva chau

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La respuesa con CSS. Para alinear el contenido, debes darle al interior la propiedad grid y  utilizar el alineamiento de cajas. Aquí tienes más información sobre el alineamiento de cajas con `grid layout`; [Box alignment in CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)

No se como tienes el código dentro del contenedor porque no has puesto el código, pero suponiendo que tengas contenedores `div` dentro del contenedor principal, con align-items puedes alinear el contenido de los `div`que están dentro del contenedor principal.

```css
#contenedor {
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%; 
  column-gap:.5rem; 
  grid-row-gap:.5rem;
}

#contenedor>div {
  border: solid 1px;
  display:grid;
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div>Contenedor</div>
  <div>
    Contenedor<br>
    Caja 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Contenedor<br>
    Caja 3<br>
    Derecha
  </div>
  <div>Contenedor</div>
  <div>Contenedor</div>
  <div>Contenedor</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución alternativa es utilizar el layout de columnas. En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo texto pero tu puedes utilizar imágenes.

```css
main {
  color:#333;
  font-family:verdana;
  line-height:150%;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
.card {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-radius:.5em;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: inline-block;/*para evitar que el card se rompa entre columnas*/
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article class = "card"><strong>1.</strong> La vella i fràgil plata esdevé tarda parada en la claror damunt els camps. Vàrem mirar ben al lluny del desert, davallàvem al fons del nostre somni.</article>
  <article class = "card"><strong>2.</strong> Escolta, Sepharad: els homes no poden ser si no són lliures․ Que sàpiga Sepharad que no podrem mai ser si no som lliures. Si topem a les palpentes amb aquest estrany cec, on sinó en el buit i en el no-res fonamentarem la nostra vida?</article>
  <article class = "card"><strong>3.</strong> La terra, amb paranys de mil fines orelles, ha captivat els ocells de les cançons de l'aire. Ara digueu: Ens mantindrem fidels per sempre més al servei d'aquest poble. Si topem a les palpentes amb aquest estrany cec, on sinó en el buit i en el no-res fonamentarem la nostra vida? Provarem d'alçar en la sorra el palau perillós dels nostres somnis i aprendrem aquesta lliçó humil.</article>
  <article class = "card"><strong>4.</strong> Ara digueu: La ginesta floreix, arreu als camps hi ha vermell de roselles․ Amb nova falç comencem a segar el blat madur i, amb ell, les males herbes. Que sàpiga Sepharad que no podrem mai ser si no som lliures.</article>
  <article class = "card"><strong>5.</strong> Provarem d'alçar en la sorra el palau perillós dels nostres somnis i aprendrem aquesta lliçó humil. Ai, com guiar aquest immens dolor al clos de les paraules de la nit? Passen el vent, el triomf, el repòs, per rengles d'altes flames i d'arquers.
  Ara digueu: Ens mantindrem fidels per sempre més al servei d'aquest poble.</article>
  <article class = "card"><strong>6.</strong> Vàrem mirar ben al lluny del desert, davallàvem al fons del nostre somni.</article>
</main>
```

Comment: excelente, voy a probar